# R XML + XPath - getNodeSet with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm new to XPath - please go easy on me.

Having trouble extracting XPath on my target pages for elements that don't have a lot of  structure.

The data set is NJ school [report cards](http://education.state.nj.us/rc/rc11/nav.php?c=0).  Individual report cards look like [this](http://education.state.nj.us/rc/rc11/rcreport.php?c=01;d=0110;s=100)

I've figured out how to pull out tables that have a `summary` tag:

```
url <- paste("http://education.state.nj.us/rc/rc11/rcreport.php?c=",
  all_sch[i,1],";d=",all_sch[i,2],";s=",all_sch[i,3],sep = '')
doc = htmlParse(url)
admin_salaries = getNodeSet(doc, '//table[@summary="Administrative Salaries and Benefits"]')
```

but am having trouble where there isn't a lot of extra identifying information to work off of.

For instance, the table that has school name and district looks like this:

```
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><strong>SCHOOL:</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;New Jersey Ave</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>COUNTY:</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;Atlantic</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>DISTRICT:</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;Atlantic City</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

My strategy here was 'find nodes that are tables and have the text `COUNTY`

[Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599198/select-on-multiple-criteria-with-xpath) as much as I can about XPath, I'm trying this:

```
names = getNodeSet(doc,'//table and //*[contains(text(),"COUNTY")]')
```

But instead of returning back the table node, it gives me a boolean `TRUE` value.

So, the question is: **How can I use XPath to find tables that have the text COUNTY and SCHOOL?**

I've tried a lot of other strategies to little avail.  One approach suggested by others was simply to pull out every table data cell using something like this:

```
xpathApply( htmlTreeParse(url, useInt=T), "//td", function(x) xmlValue(x))
```

But the templates aren't consistent for missing data - incomplete reports have pretty different structure, and elements aren't in the same position across the 2,000+ pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using xpath, to get all the table

```
xpathSApply( doc, "//table[contains(.,'SCHOOL:') 
                  and contains(.,'COUNTY') ]",xmlValue)
```

To get just the row

```
xpathSApply( doc, "//tr/td[contains(.,'SCHOOL:') 
                   and contains(.,'COUNTY') ]",xmlValue)
```