# XPath to Capture Alternating Rows

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Using `HtmlAgilityPack`, I am trying to capture rows of a table where the row class name alternates.  Snippet below:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var documentNode = doc.DocumentNode;
var lstNodes = documentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='rgMasterTable']");
var tableNode = lstNodes[0];
var rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='rgRow dnnGridItem'|@class='rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem']");
```

On the last line, I am trying to say "Give me rows where the class is either `rgRow dnnGridItem` or `rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem`.  However, I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
```

The source of the HTML is available here: http://www.terna.it/it-it/sistemaelettrico/remit.aspx

Any assistance on the correct XPath query greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you provide sample of the HTML?

Comment: I thought that the question should be clear enough without, and the HTML would only add clutter.  Link provided for those interested.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599198/select-on-multiple-criteria-with-xpath - looks you should instead union the two selectors instead of having expression in the criteria.

Comment: @LukášDoležal - that worked.  Code becomes:
var rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='rgRow dnnGridItem'] | //tr[@class='rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem']");

Comment: you can write it shoter `"//tr[@class='rgRow dnnGridItem' or @class='rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem']"` just change union with `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to link from @LukášDoležal : [Select on multiple criteria with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599198/select-on-multiple-criteria-with-xpath)

The UNION should be on the nodes, not on the class specification.

```
var rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='rgRow dnnGridItem'|@class='rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem']");
```

becomes

```
var rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='rgRow dnnGridItem'] | //tr[@class='rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem']");
```

or shorter yet (thanks to @splash58):

```
var rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='rgRow dnnGridItem' or @class='rgAltRow dnnGridAltItem']");
```